# Showing all session data at once?

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried the following but it is giving me errors:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

How can I show all session data in CodeIgniter?

Comment: I asked this question yesterday... Searching for your question first will speed up your fixies!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

or

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Update:

As of version 3.1.11 the above methods are [deprecated](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#class-reference). Use the below method to get all [session](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data) data,

```
print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Answer (score 10):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
echo "</pre>";
```

Display yet formatting then you can view properly.

Answer (score 1):

For print session data you do not need to use print_r() function every time .

If you use it then it will be non-readable format.Data will be looks very dirty.

But if you use my function all you have to do is to use p()-Funtion and pass data into it.
//create new file into application/cms_helper.php and load helper cms into //autoload or on controller

/*Copy Code for p function from here and paste into cms_helper.php in application/helpers folder  */

```
   //@parram $data-array,$d-if true then die by default it is false
   //@author Your name

    function p($data,$d = false){

          echo "<pre>"; 
             print_r($data);
          echo "</pre>"; 

        if($d == TRUE){
             die();
          } 
      }
```

Just remember to load cms_helper into your project or controller using $this->load->helper('cms'); use bellow code into your controller or model it will works just GREAT.

```
 p($this->session->all_userdata()); // it will apply pre to your sesison data and other array as  well
```

Answer (score 1):

here is code:

```
<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>
```